# Excel VBA Userform won't work on all computers

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a user's form using VBA excel code. Its working fine on my laptop however when I tried it on my office computer it doesn't work. I emailed the file to myself and downloaded it from Outlook in the office. Its a .xlsm file. It gives me an error message that macros have been disabled. I have already changed settings to enable macros and allow VBA projects. I reopened excel and checked again it still doesn't work. The downloaded file from outlook, when I click visual basic, it doesn't show me any user form or code at all. Not sure why.

My whole code is present in the user form part (file in a personal laptop). There is a button on "sheet 3" which basically opens the user form. Not sure if it's saving the code only locally on my computer. As per my understanding if it's saved in the file it should be a part of it even if its opened on any other computer. My laptop version is office 365 and office one is 2016. I am not an advanced user. Kindly advise what is the error out here.

Comment: This is normal behavior, given you're opening an attachment. Save the attached .xlsm locally, then open it from its location. Other than that, pretty hard to guess what might be wrong with code we can't see.

Comment: It might also be related to Excel still realizing this is a downloaded file. Check the file properties from the context menu in the normal Explorer. Below the "Read only" and "Hidden" flag there could be another section "Security" stating that the file comes from a different computer. Next to that hint is a third checkbox to allow access. Tick that and check if that helps.